# How to get base url with tenant in orchard?

Tags: orchardcms

How to get the base url with tenant prefix in Orchard? I have a tenant root url, for example `domain.com/tenant`.

```
var httpContextAccessor = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver.GetService(typeof(IHttpContextAccessor)) as IHttpContextAccessor;
var workContext = WorkContextExtensions.GetWorkContext(httpContextAccessor.Current().Request.RequestContext);
return workContext.CurrentSite.BaseUrl;
```

When I use this code, I get only http:\domain.com, without tenant prefix.

Thanks a lot for answer.

Comment: I can't check it now but just take a look at the Request object in the debugger, it's somewhere there (or if not, then somewhere else a level higher in HttpContext).

Comment: Thanks, I thing, that there it is. But when I dont know if its tennant or root web, I dont know whitch slash is root, when there are for example domain.com/tennant/item or domain.com/blog/blogitem.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ShellSettings`. This object contains all the tenant information defined in Settings.txt file.

```
var settings = workContext.Resolve<ShellSettings>();
var host = settings.RequestUrlHost;  
var prefix = settings.RequestUrlPrefix;
```

Now you need to combine the base URL you already got with tenant prefix above.

If you want to get a relative path that takes into account the current tenant, use `Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath`. Eg. If your tenant is `example.com/tenant` and you are requesting page `example.com/tenant/mypage` it will return `~/mypage`. Depending on your scenario, this might also become useful.